# How to change orientation of toolbar which is adding to window

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad

I am developing one app which is based on tabbarcontroller.In one view Controller i want to hidden the tabbarController instead of that i want to show toolbar for that purpose i wrote the following code

```
    //tabBAr hidden
    [self.tabBarController.tabBar setHidden:YES];
    //creation of tool bar
    AppDelegate *delegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
     tb = [[UIToolbar alloc] init];
    //[tb setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tabbar.png"] forToolbarPosition:UIToolbarPositionAny barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    tb.tintColor = [[UIColor blackColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.6];
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice]userInterfaceIdiom]==UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
    {
        tb.frame = CGRectMake(0, delegate.window.frame.size.height-50, 320, 44);

    }
    else
    {
        tb.frame = CGRectMake(0, delegate.window.frame.size.height-70, 768, 44);
    }

    [delegate.window addSubview:tb];
```

But problem is in iPad i want to change orientation of toolbar but it does not change it always takes portrait width and height.

Answer (score 0):

Use notification to detect the device orientation like the following.

```
// Start Orientation //
- (void)orientationChanged:(NSNotification *)notification{
    [self adjustViewsForOrientation:[[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation]];
}

- (void) adjustViewsForOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation) orientation {

    if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)
    {
        //NSLog(@"Vertical");

    }
    else if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
    {
        //NSLog(@"Horizontal");

    }
}
// End Orientation //

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self  selector:@selector(orientationChanged:) name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification  object:nil];
}
```

Somebody has kindly written this notification code somewhere.  I didn't write it.

Answer (score 0):

use viewWillLayoutSubViews method and add code to setFrame of toolbar in that method

ex:

```
- (void) viewWillLayoutSubviews
{
     [toolBar setFrmae:CGRectMake(self.view.bounds.origin.x, self.view.bounds.size.height - 44, self.view.bounds.size.width, 44)];
}
```